OpenModelica incompatible assignment error
why do we get this compilation error and what does this error mean?
ABCDE_03lsy.c:115:79: error: assigning to 'modelica_real' (aka 'double') from incompatible type 'real_array' (aka 'struct base_array_s')
  115 |   (parentJacobian->tmpVars[22]) /* MWout.$pDERB.dummyVarB JACOBIAN_TMP_VAR */ = mul_alloc_real_array_scalar(tmp1, (parentJacobian->tmpVars[0]) /* $cse7 JACOBIAN_TMP_VAR */);



Most likely a bug in the compiler. It tries to bind a real to an array in the generated code.  Please open a ticket with more details, if possible with a minimal example: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/new/choose

@Adrian Pop posted the issue. https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/12316
